# Did the Borg originally have another name (and if so, what was it)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg, behind-the-scenes

According to information found, among other places, in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22718/is-the-term-borg-an-acronym-for-something-or-is-it-just-an-abbreviation-of-c), the name *Borg* is an abbreviated version of *Cyborg*, referring to the nature of the Borg.

As can also be found in various sources, for instance cited by [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg#Background_information), the Borg were originally intended to be an insectoid species. This is in line with the parasite bugs from [TNG: *Conspiracy*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Conspiracy_%28episode%29) having been planned as [the first Borg invasion wave](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Neural_parasite_%2824th_century%29#Background) (although this latter claim is [not necessarily trustworthy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22963/21137)).

In any case, while I have read about the Borg being originally planned as an insectoid species, they seem to be invariably referred to as *Borg*. Based on the aforementioned ethymology of that name, however, it is unlikely the originally planned insectoid species would have been called *Borg*, as well.

**Did the Borg have another name then used by the production team and if so, what was it?**

Comment: Big bad beetle borgs was taken.

Comment: The conspiracy aliens were only chosen because Roddenberry vetoed a internal federation human coup. **cough cough into darkness** They were a last minute change.

Comment: @cde: As much as Into Darkness makes me cough myself, [we don't have to go that far](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Paradise_Lost_%28episode%29).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The difference is, Paradise Lost made sense.

Comment: The moral eclipse of Into Darkness is worse. DS9 Admiral was doing it because of an active war with infiltraters. Into Darkness Admiral was a war monger looking to start a war and subjugate the Klingons. But I digress,

Comment: Off topic: If you have not read the Star Trek Manga origin of the Borg - ['Side Effects'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_%28Star_Trek%29#Origin) - you really should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Not as far as I can tell.**

The various references to Hurley's original idea of an insectoid species seem to come from two main sources; the [Captains' Logs](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captains'_Logs:_The_Unauthorized_Complete_Trek_Voyages) book and the [TNG Companion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Companion), that both refer to this as having been a *concept* that was abandoned at an early stage:

> Although the Borg began as a race of insects, a concept dropped for
>   budget reasons, their relentless mentality survived. - <sub><sup>TNG
>   Companion</sup></sub>

and

> Maurice Hurley offers, “A good one. It was an attempt to create some
>   new jeopardy, a new villain. You have to have an adversary that’s
>   worthy, so you made it impossible to defeat them. What we really
>   wanted to do, but couldn't because of money, was insects. Insect
>   mentality is great, because it is relentless. The Borg are a variation
>   of an insect mentality. They don't care. They have no mercy, no
>   feelings towards you. They have their own agenda and that's it. If all
>   of them die getting there, they don't care. If you want some bad
>   asses, there you go!” - <sub><sup>Captains' Logs: The Unauthorized Complete Trek Voyages</sup></sub>

Although it's impossible to prove a negative, the total absence of any [concept art](http://ottens.co.uk/forgottentrek/creating-the-borg/), finer discussion of the insect race's characteristics or any input from other members of the production team would tend to suggest that this was an idea that they kicked around *verbally* before discarding in favour of the more budget-friendly Borg.

Comment: I've accepted this for now, notwithstanding any future findings about the insect-Borg having had a different name.

Comment: Glad, the cyborg killing machines were way better than that. And to me "Terminator" is inferior to the Borg. The Borg are scarier, and plus they're rooted in historical reality making them very creepy. Sweden, the country for who via the obvious name for the alien beings, did a lot of horrible things in their time as an Allied colonizer.

Comment: If they had kept the bugs it would have been boring. The concept of unbeatable cyborg killing machines is way better